# How to delete a model with an world plugin

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I wrote a WorldPlugin similar to the [factory example](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/2.2/plugins/Factory) and now I want to delete a added model but how?
The following approach does not work :-(

```
void delete(const std::string& name){
    # Info world_ is of type physics::WorldPtr 
    physics::ModelPtr p = world_->GetModel(name);
    p->RemoveChildren();        
}
```

Greetings
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5887/how-to-delete-a-model-with-an-world-plugin/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/491/markus-bader/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-04-10**:
try `p->Fini();` ?

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/491/markus-bader/) on 2014-04-10**:
Thanks Andrei, Fini worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Based on Andrei's comment I changed my code and now it works.

Thanks to Andrei :-)

```
void delete(const std::string& name){
    # Info world_ is of type physics::WorldPtr 
    physics::ModelPtr p = world_->GetModel(name);
    p->Fini();        
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/491/markus-bader/) with karma: 61 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0